# "Think of somebody" or "think somebody as" or "think of somebody as"

Tags: prepositions, american-english

> I think of you a good person
>   I think you as a good person
>   I think of you as a good person

Which one is correct?

Comment: Idiomatically one would naturally expect to hear the far more direct *I think you **are** a good person*, so you'd need to have some *reason* for choosing to use this alternative (only the last is syntactically valid). With no other context to guide me, if I heard the "indirect, circumlocutory" version, I'd assume the next word was going to be ***but...***

Answer (score 1):

"I think of you as a good person" 
This breaks down into three phrases

- I think ( this could be a complete sentence by itself )
- of you ( prepositional phrase, showing what I think of. Of you)
- as a good person ( prepositional phrase, showing how I think of you. As a good person)

Comment: I wonder whether "*as a good person*" defines "*you*" or "*think*"...

Comment: This sentence could be re-written as "I think you are a good person" with nearly the same meaning. "as a good person" goes with "you"

Comment: If it is connected to "you", it is an **attributive phrase**, yes? But your third bullet item ("showing ***how*** I think of you") suggests **adverbial phrase** defining "think".

Comment: I was thinking of it as an **adjective phrase** when I said it went with "you", but you are correct it is an **adverb phrase** because it goes with "think". It cannot be **attributive** because "you" hasn't done anything to receive attribution for.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I don't have the rep to comment on your answer, but you're missing the the article: **"I think you are a good person**

Comment: You mean I am missing the verb, surely (not the the article).  If so, no, I am not missing anything.  In this phrase "think"="consider", in spoken language those sometimes take each other's places.  You don't have anything against "I consider you a good person", do you?

Answer (score 0):

.When you have a particular opinion about someone/something or regard him/it as specified, you can use either the structure think + of + somebody + as something or think + somebody + something. But it's better to use the first structure as it's more common and idiomatic.  Please look at the following sentences taken from McMillan Dictionary:

Nobody thought of him as a candidate for the job.

I thought him a very nice young man.

In light of this rule, the first two sentences are incorrect grammatically, whereas the third one as follows is correct:

I think of you as a good person.

Alternatively, you can say:

I think you a good person.

In more simple words, you can say "I think you are a good person".

Answer (score -1):

Ron's answer gives one acceptable variant.  Another, not among your three, is

> I think you a good person.

Comment: This a rather stilted and dated (if not actually *archaic*) usage. I don't think it should be promoted on a *learners* site without that caveat being made clear.